# Expand regex for money checking the amount

Tags: html, regex, input, currency

I have a regex that checks the value of an HTML input, if it fits the right form for money:

```
^(?=\(.*\)|[^()]*$)\(?\d{1,3}(,?\d{3})?(\.\d\d?)?\)?\€?$
```

Now I need to expand the regex so that it also checks that the amount of money is bigger than 0.40€.

Allowed examples :

```
25€
25
25.00
25.00€
25,00
25,00€
0.99€
0.99
0,99
0,99€
```

Not allowed:

```
0.39
0.39€
0,39
0,39€
```

Comment: After you validate the format, you could safely convert it to a numeric value and do a simple comparison (or a more complicated one when your rules change).

Comment: The strategy is to check if it is 0[.][4-9] or [1-9]\d*[.]

Comment: I'm afraid that `0,99` is not match with your regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the pattern you posted leads to wrong results ([see here](http://regex101.com/r/hI3jY4)) as not all of your allowed input is matched.

Assuming your're using JS here's another regex you may use, which includes the check for `> 0.4`:

```
^(?:(?:[1-9][0-9]*(?:(?:.|,)\d{2})?)|(?:0(?:(?:.|,)(?:4[1-9]|[5-9]\d))))€?$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/0MVaPNE_2kYJuHad)
[regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/aS8gE0)

This **excludes 0.40**, because I interpret your `bigger than 0.40€` as `> 0.4`.

In case you meant `>= 0.4` you can use

```
^(?:(?:[1-9][0-9]*(?:(?:.|,)\d{2})?)|(?:0(?:(?:.|,)[4-9]\d)))€?$
```

Comment: `[4-9][1-9]` would not match 0.90 cents, you probably meant [4-9]\d

Comment: @cDima thanks! you're right, it won't match anything with a trailing zero. But I interpret _bigger than 0.40_ as `> 0.4`, so excluding `0.40`. I'll add both options to my answer...

Comment: Sry but i weren't very accurate with my examples ... so it needs to allow all money values over 0.40€ so yours doesnt allow 100€ or 1000€ or so many other amounts of money.

Comment: @user3179168 no problem, just added another restriction for the first character groups, now it allows all values above 0.4

Comment: Oh yeah ! Thanks alot. I will try it out at home if it will work fine in my html input element.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me, matching the needed strings.

```
/^(\d{1,3}([,\.][4-9]\d)?|([1-9]{1,3}([,\.]\d\d)?))\€?$/gm
```

http://refiddle.co/h2f